# Spark shell throwing exception after trying to integrate s3 / hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm working on a windows machine trying to set up a spark teststack - the aim is to read/write file to an s3 bucket.

I'm running 1.6.1.  When I run spark-shell I now receive an error:

```
16/03/22 15:19:48 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
16/03/22 15:19:48 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=Administrator   ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=*
16/03/22 15:19:48 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
```

doing some reading lead me to believe that I need to add the aws jars as an argument - the jars are included in the hadoop structure.

I then run `C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\tools\lib>spark-shell --jars aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar, hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar`

thinking that I'm now including the jars and so it must be ok...how foolish of me - I get the exact same error.

I then tried to include just the hadoop-aws jar and all kinds of exceptions were thrown including not being able to instantiate hive, s3a couldn't be instantiated, awscredentials wasn't happy and so on.

I'm at a bit of a loss, if anyone can shed some light on what I might be doing wrong I'll happily buy them a  pint :)

EDIT:
I've since updates the core-site.xml file, by removing the fs.defaultFS property witha  value os s3n://mybucketname, spark will now load.
In it's stead i have the hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000 which is working fine.

Soi I guess my question changes from 'gaaaaah to 'gaaaaah, how does one include s3 correctly as a filesystem'